# exclude properties from flow type

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have a two components, `<BlockButton />` and `<PrimaryButton />`, which wrap `<Button />`. `Button` is defined in flow as follows:

```
declare export type ButtonProps = {|
  block?: boolean,
  bsClass?: 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'default',
  // plus many more
|}
declare export class Button extends React$Component {
  props: ButtonProps;
}
```

Is there any nice way to make `BlockButtonProps` be defined in terms of `ButtonProps`, but exclude the `block` property? I don't want to divide `ButtonProps` into three parts: `base`, `bsClass` and `block`, because that would get untenable and brittle very quickly.

I'd like this to work whether `block` and `bsClass` are optional or required, although that is not strictly necessary at this point.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without splitting it the other way around. I've never seen a way to exclude properties of a type.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I figured from reading the docs.